# A world without mass religion?

Tags: religion

I was talking to one of my friends about religion, and she talked about a very interesting idea.

Instead of not believing in God, you create your own personal God. For one person their God might be benevolent and helpful, for another a harsh taskmaster, it all depends on the person.

The positive effect is that there would be no religious quarrels, discrimination, and all.

But there are a few downsides as well, like a psychopath whose God wants all left-handed people to be killed.

If we had a society without religion, with only individual Gods, what would it possibly be like?

Edit: What I mean is that suddenly everyone forgets religion and starts believing in personal Gods. I'm ignoring why or how that happened, but this scenario raises question like if mass religion could be revived, if people would agree to believing other people's Gods without those Gods having the support of preestablished structure and support.

Comment: This is a very broad question with a lot of different things that need to be accounted for. For example we would have to think back to the beginnings of humanity to start answering this and then remove the ability to convince other humans from your ideas - because I have my god and why wouldn't I want to tell you about how awesome my god is? If you trust my awesome god instead of your lame one we would both be super awesome. Are there certain aspects you are specifically interested in and when do you start this change? For the moment I am voting to temporarily put this on hold as "too broad".

Comment: @Secespitus No, I didn't mean that. I meant that, one day, everyone suddenly forgets religion and starts believing in their own Gods. The ability to convince people is important. Would people want to believe in other's Gods without the God having the support of preestablished structure? And so on.

Comment: Questions asking "what would society be like if X was different" are generally put on hold as being too broad. The general rule of thumb is that if the answer to a question could take up an entire book, it's too broad, and this fails that test in my opinion.

Comment: @F1Krazy No one wants answers that would fill a book. Partial answer would be acceptable, and even preferred. Maybe someone writes about the political climate, while someone discusses changes in daily life, like that?

Comment: Sometimes that would be preferred by the person asking, but sadly this is not how the StackExchange Q&A idea works. The goal is to have one question with one best answer and possibly a few answers that are rated lower. But each answer should fully answer the question asked and not depend on others. StackExchange is meant to be different from other forums where partial answers are accepted. Partial answers or comment-like answers are quite often deleted as they don't meat the criteria for being *complete* answers. That's why the book-test is so important here on WorldBuilding.

Comment: Basically that's already what is going on in most western and protestant (lutheran) countries I would argue. Even if you disagree, you have to agree on that the psychopaths that think god wants them to kill all lefties exist either way and are not more of a problem in your world.

Comment: For completeness sake: if you would like open-ended discussions about hypothetical opinion-based and very broad topics in a more forum-like manner the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) might be the place to go. We like to have such discussions there. Sometimes there is quite a lot of discussion going on and it's a great place to get some quick feedback on "What comes to your mind if I throw the following premise into the room: "-type requests. Check it out if you have the time. It can be quiet sometimes, but it can be very active, too. Depends on the time.

Comment: @Secespitus Thanks for the suggestion. Will try it in case the question is closed. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: It's just a tip in case you want to give it a try. Many people don't know about the chat as it's a bit hidden, because SE focuses on the Q&A part and less about the socialising parts that you see on other forums. BTW: Your edit is good in addressing my concerns about when this whole thing started. But I still think that discussing all of society is too much. And this seems similar to the beginning of humanity. We didn't have a couple of big religions, but they still emerged at some point. And before that everyone must have had their own ideas.

Comment: Please note that humans are social in nature.  We want to be in like-minded groups.  If you magically reset our religious structure such that all forget it and begin to believe in personal gods, it would take no time at all for people to either (a) pleasantly say "hey, your god sounds a lot like my god, they must be the same god!" and build a church or (b) violently say, "your god is false, only mine is true, believe or burn!" and build a church.  Only an anti-social people could effectively believe in individually disparate gods.

Comment: People already do that, even in organized religions... especially in organized religions.
“In the beginning God created man in His own image, and man has been trying to repay the favor ever since.” ― Voltaire